# Linux на windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, git-bash

Хочу прокачаться в линуксе, но у меня стоит винда и мне нельзя ставить другую операционку. Подскажите, может, можно поставить какой нибудь шуточный линукс типа командной строки чтобы он интерпретировал команды из линукса в винду, или мот есть какая нибудь десктопная программа, может, подойдет git bash? Или что то в этом духе

Comment: VirtualBox, либо WSL

Comment: Скачайте в Microsoft Store любой интересующий вас дистрибутив. Напишите просто - "Linux" в поиске маркета. Если нужен в основном только для выполнения операций в терминале, то это ваш вариант. Думаю, это будет намного лучше, чем заморачиваться с VirtualBox и виртуализацией, если конечно вам сразу не нужен дистрибутив с GUI. Но в принципе для WSL тоже можно прикрутить GUI

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Можете сделать [образ на флешке](https://www.tecmint.com/install-linux-os-on-usb-drive/) и работать с него

Comment: Для староверов есть ещё cygwin.

Comment: Git bash норм, там есть несколько утилит, но не все

Comment: альтернативный вариант - подкачаться в powershell

Comment: https://www.cygwin.com/ довольно матерый эмулятр для винды

Comment: Супер! Спасибо всем))

Comment: А почему нельзя?